# How to convert between collection types - Set to ListSet in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a `Set` in my code which i need to transfer to `ListSet`. It feels like a very easy thing to do, but i feel like an idiot not to be able to do it

Some code to illustrate the issue:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListSet

val someData = Set(1,2,3)

//Need to transfer to ListSet
val listSetOfData: ListSet[Int] = someData.toListSet //?
```

Please assist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala 2.12 (and presumably future Scala versions) you can use the `to` method to convert to practically any collection type:

```
scala> someData.to[ListSet]
res0: scala.collection.immutable.ListSet[Int] = ListSet(1, 2, 3)
```

In 2.11 and earlier you'll see people use a number of different ways to do this kind of thing:

```
scala> ListSet(someData.toSeq: _*)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.ListSet[Int] = ListSet(1, 2, 3)

scala> ListSet.empty[Int] ++ someData
res2: scala.collection.immutable.ListSet[Int] = ListSet(1, 2, 3)
```

Personally I think I prefer the `++` version, but it's largely a matter of taste.

Comment: Great, thanks. It is simple, but i guess everything is simple once you know what you are doing..